# Prove that $\varphi(2n)=2\varphi(n)$ if $n$ is even.

Tags: number-theory

So, far, I have the following which I have seen the basic idea in other similar proofs:

Let $n$ be an even, positive integer. Then $n=2^{s}(p_{1}^{x_{1}}\cdot p_{2}^{x_{2}} \cdot\cdot\cdot p_{r}^{x_{r}})$ since $n$ is even, where $p_{r}$ is an odd prime number and $x$ is an positive integer. Then $\frac{n}{2^{s}}$ is odd, and so it is relatively prime to $2^{s}$ which is even. But $n=2^{s}\cdot \frac{n}{2^{s}}$, which implies that $\varphi(n)=\varphi(2^{s}) \cdot \varphi(\frac{n}{2^{s}})$.

I am hoping to somehow get $2$ out of $\varphi(2^{s})$ and combine the leftovers with the term $\varphi(\frac{n}{2^{s}})$, but not sure if it's possible? It seems like I keep end up proving the statement false, when it should be true...is there a clear way to finish this, or is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: Possible repeated http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440557/for-what-integers-n-does-phi2n-phin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write $n = 2^k\cdot m$ where $m$ is odd. Then
$$\varphi(2n) = \varphi(2^{k+1} \cdot m) = \varphi(2^{k+1})\varphi(m) = 2^k\varphi(m) = 2\varphi(2^k)\varphi(m) = 2\varphi(n).$$

Comment: Interesting one. Thank you - it's clever manipulations. But why does $k$ have to be odd?

Comment: That should probably read $m$ is odd.

Answer (score -1):

Since $n$ is odd, $\gcd(2,n)=1$.

> $$\varphi(2n) = \varphi(2)\varphi(n) = 1\varphi(n)$$

Since $n$ is even, $n = 2^km$

> $$\varphi(2n) = \varphi(2\cdot 2^km) = \varphi(2^{k+1}m) = \varphi(2^{k+1})\varphi(m)= 2^k\varphi(m)= $$$$2\cdot 2^{k-1}\varphi(m)=2\cdot \varphi(2^k)\varphi(m)=2\cdot \varphi(2^km) = 2\varphi(n)$$

Comment: This prove uses the multiplicativity of the totient-function, but this does not hold in general : For example $\phi(4)=2$ , $\phi(8)=4$ , $\phi(4\cdot 8)=\phi(32)=16\ne 2\cdot 4$

Comment: The multiplicativity is true for coprime arguments , but if we assume that $n$ is even , $2$ and $n$ are NOT coprime.

Comment: You are right. Thank you for your comment. :)